# Raspberry Pi HQ Camera: Capture NEF or DNG?

Tags: python, camera, picamera

I'm making a raw capture tool for raspberry pi and the official HQ camera. I can't seem to get RAW DNG or TIFF images, whatever I do. Here's my current code:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
print('Import successful!')
print("Capturing!")
with PiCamera() as cam:
    cam.capture("out.nef", format="raw", bayer="true")
print('Converting...')
import rawpy
import imageio

path = 'out.nef'
with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess()
imageio.imsave('default.tiff', rgb)
```

I tried PiDNG, but it seems to have lost support for the legacy camera stack. Please help!

Comment: Why are you not using the new PiCamera2 library? From a quick google https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/issues/318

Comment: Wait. PiCamera2 works with the HQ camera?

Comment: Yes, works with all Pi cameras.

Comment: Ooh, thanks for clarifying!